# Android Things -> Flickering while controlling 8x8 LED matrix by 74hc595 multiplexing

Tags: java, android, raspberry-pi3, android-things

Hi I am stuck while i was trying to control 8x8 led matrix by cascading two 74hc595 shift registers. I had build the circuit and the program, which I am including here. It's actually giving me the right output. But the major problem is visible flickering. Can somebody guide me what can i do to remove the flickering?

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private static final String SR_SRCLK_PIN = "BCM27";  //clock pins shcp
    private static final String SR_RCLK_PIN = "BCM18";  //latch pin   stcp
    private static final String SR_SDI_PIN = "BCM17";  //data pin
    private static final String TAG = "MAT21";

    private Gpio mRCLK;
    private Gpio mSRCLK;
    private Gpio mSDI;
    private int charSeq=0;

    int data[]=
    {
                0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00, //NULL
                0x00,0x00,0x3C,0x42,0x42,0x3C,0x00,0x00, //0
                0x00,0x00,0x00,0x44,0x7E,0x40,0x00,0x00, //1
                0x00,0x00,0x44,0x62,0x52,0x4C,0x00,0x00, //2
                0x00,0x00,0x78,0x14,0x12,0x14,0x78,0x00, //A
                0x00,0x00,0x60,0x90,0x90,0xFE,0x00,0x00, //d
                0x00,0x00,0x1C,0x2A,0x2A,0x2A,0x24,0x00, //e
                0x00,0x00,0x7E,0x12,0x12,0x0C,0x00,0x00, //p
                0x00,0x00,0x08,0x7E,0x88,0x40,0x00,0x00, //t
                0x3C,0x42,0x95,0xB1,0xB1,0x95,0x42,0x3C, //:)
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        PeripheralManagerService pms = new PeripheralManagerService();
        try {
            mRCLK = pms.openGpio(SR_RCLK_PIN);
            mRCLK.setDirection(Gpio.DIRECTION_OUT_INITIALLY_LOW);
            mSRCLK = pms.openGpio(SR_SRCLK_PIN);
            mSRCLK.setDirection(Gpio.DIRECTION_OUT_INITIALLY_LOW);
            mSDI = pms.openGpio(SR_SDI_PIN);
            mSDI.setDirection(Gpio.DIRECTION_OUT_INITIALLY_LOW);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error on PeripheralIO API", e);
        }

        try {
            thread.start();
                while (true){
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                    charSeq++;
                    if(charSeq==10){
                        charSeq=0;
                    }
                }
        } catch (Exception sd) {

        }
    }

    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                while (true) {
                    for (int rowNum = 0; rowNum < 8; rowNum++) {
                        mRCLK.setValue(false);
                        shiftOut(data[(charSeq * 8) + rowNum],rowNum);
                        mRCLK.setValue(true);
                    }
                }
            }catch (Exception ex){

            }
        }
    });

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        // Clean all resources
        if (mSDI != null) {
            try {
                mSDI.setValue(false);
                mSDI.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error on PeripheralIO API", e);
            }
        }
        if (mRCLK != null) {
            try {
                mRCLK.setValue(false);
                mRCLK.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error on PeripheralIO API", e);
            }
        }
        if (mSRCLK != null) {
            try {
                mSRCLK.setValue(false);
                mSRCLK.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error on PeripheralIO API", e);
            }
        }
    }

    void shiftOut(int data, int rowNum) {
        try {
            for (int i = 7; i >= 0; i--) {
                mSRCLK.setValue(false);
                mSDI.setValue((((data >> i) & 1) == 0));
                mSRCLK.setValue(true);
            }
            for (int i = 0; i <8; i++) {
                mSRCLK.setValue(false);
                mSDI.setValue(i==rowNum?true:false);
                mSRCLK.setValue(true);
            }
        } catch (Exception sd) {

        }
    }
}
```

[Schemetic Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2zmrd.jpg)

Comment: Please add your schematics.

Comment: added. please check

Answer (score 1):

It's not entirely clear from your question what clock frequency you need to achieve to drive your matrix display properly, but regardless it's unlikely you will be able to get there bit-banging the GPIO in this fashion. The flickering you see is probably because the I/O is not toggling fast enough in your code.

I would recommend moving to an external hardware controller for your display (something like the [MAX7219](https://www.adafruit.com/product/453), for example) that you can control over a serial port like I2C or SPI.

Comment: Thanks @Devunwired. But still trying to do it same way. I got example of same program in python and c. And they are working fine. So there may be a way of doing it (I hope)